# jQuery Marquee - Resets after four entries in Firefox

Tags: jquery-plugins, marquee

Good evening everyone.

I am puzzling over the oddity that the [jQuery Marquee plugin](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/), which was working fine, suddenly resets itself after showing only four of six entries here: http://site427.mysite4now.net/tazthedog/site1/ (click on the Upcoming Events tab in the lower-right hand corner).

This works correctly in IE and Chrome on a PC, but in Firefox on a Mac and PC it resets after four.

Any ideas why it resets?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be a problem for me in Chrome 5.  What browser are you seeing this bug in?

Edit:

Ah, I got it in Firefox.  Could be any number of things.  Looks like it might be an edge detection thing.  Or the height they pull from the page isn't the proper height needed for the animation.  Chrome displays this properly, so you might want to check the "hitedge" and  "height" variables to make sure they are properly assigned and defined.  It could also be a timing thing or some sort of event delay with Firefox.  Try upgrading to the latest version of jquery 1.4.2 to see if that resolves anything.

Comment: I am seeing it in Firefox and Safari.

Comment: It is indeed a Firefox issue and I don't have an answer at this point. I upgraded to 1.4.2 and the problems still persists. I'll just have to keep looking. Thanks for your help